# Bookmark CoreData Schema

Tags: swift, core-data

I was developing an app which let user save a website url
I’m using CoreData for the database

Idea is bookmark entity to have name(string),url(string),category(Category)as its attributes
And Category entity will be having category name(string) and totalbookmarks(Int)

What I think is there must be one to many relationship from category to bookmark with no inverse

Is it correct ?

What should be the schema and relationship for the entities of bookmark and Categories ?

Comment: It’s always a good idea to also declare the inverse relationship in Core Data and you don’t really need a total in category since you easily can use `count` in swift code (and it will be unnecessary extra work to keep the attribute up to date)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Oh great I will make it inverse and will use count instead of total in category.Other than that is this schema correct ? And what should be its delete rule ? I’m considiering Cascade for now